# Loading image tiff to PostgreSQL without use raster2pgsql?

Tags: c#, java, matlab, raster2pgsql

I can load raster data by using raster2pgsql but i don't want to use the command line.

I want to build a desktop application.

I want to use C# or Java or matlab to load raster data without using raster2pgsql.

Can you guide me on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Current PostGIS raster manuals lists only two ways: raster2pgsql or direct use of the PostGIS raster functions http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Loading_Rasters. FME is a third option http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/postgis-raster/index.php

If you want to load rasters with C#, java or I think you can either make a GUI for raster2pgsql or your own application that uses the PostGIS raster functions directly. A third option may be available soon because there is a GSoC project going on for adding PostGIS raster write support into GDAL http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PostGIS_raster_driver. If the project will be a success and driver will be integrated with GDAL you can start using it through the GDAL java, python, and C# bindings. Follow how the project is progressing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [raster2pgsql.py as a reference implementation](https://github.com/jorgeas80/QGISPostGISRasterPlugin/blob/master/raster2pgsql.py) for how certain bits work (if you don't read C).

> This is a simple utility used to dump GDAL dataset into HEX WKB stream. It's considered as a prototype of raster2pgsql tool planned to develop in future.

However, this is all chasing down the rabbit hole quite far.